# Swift Dictionary with Array Values

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

If I declare a class property as:

```
var list = Dictionary<String, StructType[]>()
```

and then try to add a value from within a class method with:

```
var structType = StructType()
list[ "A" ] = [ structType ]
```

I get a runtime EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error. However, if I declare the dictionary within the class method and add a value there is no error.

It has something to do with the dictionary having values which are arrays. If I change the declaration to something simpler, like:

```
var list = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

then within the class method:

```
list["A"] = "some string"
```

works without any issues.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I've also tried declaring:

```
var list = Dictionary<String, String[]>()
```

and there is no issue referencing the list within a class method.

```
list[ "A" ] = [ "String1", String2" ]
```

Also the class declaration:

```
var list = Dictionary<String, SomeStruct>()
```

can be referenced within a class method.

UPDATE 2:

The struct is defined as:

```
struct Firm {
    var name = ""
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Even if this weren't kosher, you shouldn't be getting a bad instruction error like that. I'd report it to Apple.

Comment: var structType = StructType() What is StructType?

Comment: Can you paste a complete piece of code that doesn't work? I have no problems running it (after adding some surrounding code)

Comment: I am just using a simple struct. I'll update the question.

Comment: bugreport.apple.com.  Just sayin'

Comment: I've met somehow similar problem and solved it by changing struct to class and subclassing it from NSObject. Sorry, I'm not sure if it will help, but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your list and class in the following way it should work fine:

```
struct StructType {
    var myInt = 0;
}

class MyClass {
    var list = Dictionary<String, StructType[]>()
    func myFunc () {
        var structType = StructType()
        list[ "A" ] = [ structType ]
    }
}


var a = MyClass()
a.myFunc()
```

Comment: Yes, the code above works fine. However, in my situation, if I add the declaration of list to the MasterViewController ( from the Master, Detail Xcode template ) and the assignment code to the viewDidLoad() function then I get the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION runtime error. It looks like it is just a Beta Bug. Another interesting thing is if the struct is changed to a class ( and an initializer added ) there is no problem with the assignment. I'll pass this on to Apple. Cheers, Todd

Comment: yes, now that you described the whole scenario, i can reproduce it as well. It seems odd that this causes an error, i'll look into it more closely later.

Answer (score 0):

The following code appears to work for me in a playground.

```
struct StructType {

}

var list = [String:[StructType]]()
var structType = StructType()
list["A"] = [structType]
```